# Microwave and Oven Reset

Tags: electrical, oven, microwave-oven

I have a Sharp Microwave and a Whirlpool Oven.  A couple of times I've noticed that they've reset and the time clock is flashing.  I've already had an electrician check the fusebox and says it is fine. Are there any explanations as to why this is happening?

Comment: Is the power going out at the time? Are other clocks in the house going blinky on you when this happens?

Comment: It happened today and it happened two weeks ago.  Those are the only clocks in the house.  I do not notice the power flicker either, although I only noticed this after the fact and it must have happened when I was out of the house.

Comment: Probable explanation is a brief power outage. In Dallas we have had periods when those were frequent and periods without outages. Some outages will reset the microwave and not the computers.  Sometimes these outages are "momentary" (less than 1 s).

Comment: The first question I would ask is, are the microwave and oven on the same circuit? I don't think they are but it is important to know. Second I would recommend you purchase one of those  single outlet power monitor and plug it into a circuit that is on all of the time (not necessarily the microwave or oven circuit). Make sure it will registar outages and frequency glitches  and see what happens when the lights are blinking. These little units are about $20 and keep in mind this is just a suggestion to see if you can isolate the problem.